# How to type hint a function that only uses a subset of a constructor's possible return types?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typechecking

I have a function that uses a GeoPandas `GeoDataFrame`, which is a subclass of a Pandas `DataFrame`. GeoPandas' `read_file()` constructor can create either a `GeoDataFrame` or `DataFrame` instance, depending on options used, but my function needs a `GeoDataFrame` to work. I've tried to type hint this thusly:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame


def my_geographic_function(input_gdf: GeoDataFrame) -> Set[Tuple[int, int]]:
    # do stuff
    return the_result
    

input_gdf = gpd.read_file("my_input_file.geojson")
result = my_geographic_function(input_gdf)
```

However, my type checker (Pylance in VS Code) reports that this isn't correct:

```
Argument of type "DataFrame | GeoDataFrame" cannot be assigned to parameter "input_gdf" of type "GeoDataFrame" in function "my_geographic_function"
```

What's the proper way to hint that only a subset of the types `read_file()` can return are valid input to `my_geographic_function()`?

Comment: Could you try doing `input_gdf: GeoDataFrame = gpd.read_file(...)` and tell me if that helps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast a typing.Union to one of its subtypes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739764/how-to-cast-a-typing-union-to-one-of-its-subtypes-in-python)